# Product removal from cart not working in MVC Music Store (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I am working in MVC Music Store. I am almost done with coding part but i stuck while doing remove item from cart part.

The code I use on the View Page is the following:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", {"id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });

    function handleUpdate() {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        // Update the page elements
        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
        }

        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
    }
</script>
```

Here is the action link

```
<td>
            <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="<%:item.RecordId %>">Remove from cart</a>
        </td>
```

http://localhost:14652/ShoppingCart# When i click on Remove cart link, it changes to this url.

```
//
    // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
    {
        // Remove the item from the cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
        string albumName = storeDB.Carts
            .Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Album.Title;

        // Remove from cart
        int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

        // Display the confirmation message
        var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
        {
            Message = Server.HtmlEncode(albumName) +
                " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
            ItemCount = itemCount,
            DeleteId = id
        };
        return Json(results);
    }
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: The url is changing because of the "#" in href of your anchor tag. You can change it to a button or remove the href attribute.    <button  class="RemoveLink" data-id="<%:item.RecordId %>">Remove from cart</button>.   However, you need to put an alert statement in $(".RemoveLink").click() handler just to see if its bound properly. Else you can use break point and test it in chrome developer tools.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Which one is showing 404. Button click event or in your n/w tab of developer tools? Did you check whether the controller name and action method name matches with url that is provide in the click event..

Comment: Now I am getting 500. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult RemoveFromCart(Int32)' in 'MVCMusicStore.Controllers.ShoppingCartController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Ok, this means the parameter in Json Load is not going correctly. But you can put a break point in your action method and change input param to (int? id) in your action method. It will allow the null values.

Comment: Kindly check updated question. I have added removecart method. When I try to add int? id Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'

Comment: if you use int? as a parameter then within the method wherever you use id, you need to use id.Value. That will get your code compiled. However, I suggest you try different approaches first. a) change [HttpPost] to ['HttpGet'] and test ---->        $.get("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5") and if that works the check with httpPost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had to change the following line from

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and everything worked after that.  I could not believe it was so simple.